# Free Crossplatform File Sync Software

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, file-synchronization

I am searching a folder / file sync software which can do the following:

- sync files from multiple source folders to a destination folder(network drive folder)
- rename duplicate files
- delete old sync files after a given time period
- highly customisable

I have tried a couple of solutions, the best one so far is [Free File Sync](http://www.freefilesync.org/), but it does not rename duplicate files and it does not delete synced files after a given time period. Does anyone have a recommendation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Couple of my students just did a presentation on syncthing - https://syncthing.net/ Looked very impressive, it may fit your needs/wants/desires.

Answer (score 1):

I used **BitTorrent Sync** before it was renamed to [Resilio](https://www.resilio.com/). It has a free and a paid plan, and I really enjoyed how it really did download the files to my Android devices instead of just pretending to do so like Dropbox does. These days I don't need that anymore, so I went back to Dropbox only, because of some folders I share with other people.

Answer (score 0):

I think [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/index.html) (free version will do the job) might be meeting your requirements.

You can define sync programs by chosing what to sync and with what to sync it, which sync "policy" to adopt (merge files, mirror folder A to folder B...), when to automatically execute these programs, schedule them...

I am not 100% sure it renames duplicate files (I have not used it in a long time), but I'm pretty sure it does if you chose the right settings.

What I am sure of is that you can define multiple sources (by simply creating several sync profiles with the same destination, that you can moreover group together so you can run them all at the same time); and that you can sync to a network folder because I used to do it.

This is anyway the most cutomizable sync software I am aware of.